# Svn branch identify issue in python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ssl, svn

In shell when I use the below command it returns me the result.

```
/volume/buildtools/bin/svn --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username neha --password negisvn info svn+ssh://test-svn.ista.net/allhere/branches/NEHA_NEGI
```

Result:

```
Path: NEHA_NEGI
URL: svn+ssh://test-svn.ista.net/allhere/branches/NEHA_NEGI
Relative URL: ^/branches/NEHA_NEGI
Repository Root: svn+ssh://test-svn.ista.net/allhere/junos-2009
Repository UUID: aff7b9c9-8b30-4cec-ba46-ed8sefb130c1
Revision: 13123131
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: Neha
Last Changed Rev: 13123132
Last Changed Date: 2022-02-04 12:26:59
```

But when I use the same command with python script it is returning me the error. I don't know why it is happening. can anyone please help me?

Error:

> ssh-agent is empty; use ssh-add to load your key(s)!

Python code:

```
def svn_check(request):
   url ='/volume/buildtools/bin/svn --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username neha --password negisvn info svn+ssh://test-svn.ista.net/allhere/branches/NEHA_NEGI'
   output, message  = subprocess.getstatusoutput(url)
   print("CMD : " + str(url))
   print("Message : " + str(message))
   print("Return Code : " + str(output_br))
   return HttpResponse(output_br)
```

Comment: Any one have any idea ??????

Comment: Hey @James Z do you have any suggestion ??

Comment: You have to ssh keys for the username `neha` for python before you use the `svn+ssh`. If you dont want that hassle then just use `https` instead of `svn+ssh`. You should get the same output.